# jenkins windows slave failing while run as service

Tags: jenkins

We have a windows jenkins  master and two slaves windows and linux slaves.When we try to intall the windows slave as service it shows errors...

```
WMI.WmiException: UnknownFailure
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , ErrorControl , StartMode , Boolean , String[] )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
```

Could you please help me....

Answer (score 0):

As I've already suggested in [an earlier reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178264/1178189) it is better not to run Jenkins as a service on Windows. I had had so many problems with it, that at a certain point I decided that the headache of constantly looking for workarounds simply does not justify the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Not the ultimate fix but a workaround. I've just came across this error and got around it by removing and re-installing the Jenkins service.

First find service name (note the difference between `SERVICE_NAME` and `DISPLAY_NAME`,

```
C:\Users\Baris>sc queryex type= service state= all | find /i "jenkins"
SERVICE_NAME: jenkinsslave-D__X
DISPLAY_NAME: Jenkins Slave
```

And delete the service by its `SERVICE_NAME`,

```
sc delete jenkinsslave-D__X
```

I also deleted all the files (just the executables and configuration, not the repositories) under Jenkins' directory but not sure if it's necessary.

Then follow the usual steps to install Jenkins as a service as described in https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service.